# Microsoft Graph SDK: use of on behalf of authentication

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, microsoft-graph-sdks

Having a hard time making this work.

Step 1: A web app authenticates the user via Azure AD.

Step 2: This web app calls a web api (API A).

Step 3: The web api API A calls another web api (API B).

Step 4: the web api API B calls Microsoft Graph on behalf of the user to access a SharePoint site. This web api API B was given permissions to Microsoft Graph as Delegate.

All examples I could find use `DelegateAuthenticationProvider` class that is no longer available in the latest Microsoft Graph SDK (NuGet package Microsoft.Graph version 5.3.0). Unfortunately, even the official Microsoft Graph GitHub is not updated to the latest version: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample

Step 1 uses Authentication flow (we are using `DefaultAzureCredential` class)

Step 2 uses the token provided in Step 1 to access API A.

Step 3 use Client credentials flow (`ClientSecretCredential` class) to authenticate the API A to use API B. I understand that I might need to carry the token from Step 1 here, so possibly this should be on-behalf-of flow instead.

Step 4 should use on-behalf-of flow (either using `ConfidentalClienteApplication.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf` or `OnBehalfOfCredential` class)

For development purposes, I'm skipping Step 3, and trying to use directly the token from Step 1 in Step 4. The Step 3 will only happen in production.

Is there an updated code where I can see my scenario implemented?

As a developer that wants to provide business solutions I find myself spending way too much time on this topic, with so many different classes, flows, etc., and I could not find an updated code on Microsoft Graph that I could use as a base, because it is outdated (the class `DelegateAuthenticationProvider` no longer exists in latest version of the SDK).

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use on-behalf-of flow because you mentioned `calls Microsoft Graph on behalf of the user`, and client credential flow is not suitable then. I have a sample code here for you.

```
StringValues authorizationToken;
HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authorizationToken);
var token = authorizationToken.ToString().Replace("Bearer ","");
var scopes = new[] { "User.Read.All" };
var tenantId = "xxxx";
var clientId = "xxxx";
var clientSecret = "xxxx";
var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, token);
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
var token2 = onBehalfOfCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, new CancellationToken()).Result.Token;
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes);
var user = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you! In the first step, it is getting the token that reflects the user authenticated in the application, correct? I have a question: for testing purposes, I'm using DefaultAzureCredential. How can I simply use DefaultAzureCredential.GetToken to quickly authenticate my user in the application? It asks for a scope, I provided my application ID but it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: ` In the first step, it is getting the token that reflects the user authenticated in the application, correct` --> yes correct. `DefaultAzureCredential` --> I'm not very familar with  it, I used it for authenticating to access azure key vault before but I didn't use it to authenticate a user. I want to double confirm with you that if you can use it to get an access token, if you can, then could you pls check the `scp` claim or the `roles` claim. by the way I'm afraid we can't use `DefaultAzureCredential` for authenticating user.

Comment: when we use any method/code didn't come from microsoft document, then microsoft won't promise it could work. so I recommend you following the official sample to do the authentication and authorization. Here's the [official samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-api), you may check them.